# Some conflicts were found in the installation area: jbr/bin/java is modified

Tags: intellij-idea

On Ubuntu, can't update to IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 because of this conflict. What's going on? How do I resolve it?

[image]

Image transcript:

> Some conflicts were found in the installation area.
>
> Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied.
> Please download this version from developer Web site and reinstall it from scratch.
> Press 'Cancel' to exit.

Comment: nice. thanks for the transcript.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

update with the tool https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/ worked for me

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: For me there is no choice to update IntelliJ in that tool. I can only install IntelliJ which install a new separate IntelliJ instance anywhere into ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/. 
For me the answer of "lyind" is the right ...

Comment: Worked for me, thank you. I had about 100+ errors like in the subject post when updating from IDEA (`2021.1` → `2021.2`). The Toolbox App appied the update from the 1st attempt.

Comment: It works. Will need to click "uninstall" the old version manually.

Comment: On Windows 10, the toolbox didn't actually update, it installed in a new user folder C:\Users\Angelos\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\WebStorm\ch-0\232.8660.143 which is ludicrous. I wanted an installation for all users, it didn't even ask me.

Comment: Thank you! Toolbox has not only solved my update issue but it's an awesome app to have running when you run multiple Jetbrains products for multiple projects

Answer (score 6):

I fought with this for a while. There's a [long thread here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215497) that suggested several things, **none of which worked for me**. In summary:

- launching IDEA from a symlinked directory caused this for some people
- some people were able to close all existing projects and apply the update from the welcome screen (it's available from a `Configure | Check for Updates` menu item on the bottom of the welcome screen).

None of that worked for me, so I eventually just downloaded a fresh full install instead of the patch :|

Comment: a fresh full install cannot update to 2020.3.1 for me

Comment: "a fresh full install worked (also) for me"

Comment: removing the jbr directory seems to help

Answer (score 5):

As @paul-praet commented, the following seems to work:

1. close IDE and terminate all java/gradle processes
2. *delete* or *move* the `jbr` sub-directory from the `idea-IU-***` directory
3. start the IDE
4. perform the update using "Check for Updates" menu entry

Comment: works well for me, easy although one might think it's a bit hacky, but what the ... ;)

Comment: Worked for me, but after I moved the jbr folder, the fonts in the IDE looked really weird. That's why I re-added the jbr folder after the update.

Answer (score 2):

I did this before updating and it worked perfectly:

```sh
$ chmod 777 jbr/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when updating to 2021.2 For me none of the answers worked.
The only thing that worked for me was to download Intellij from Jetbrains website and install it over the old one (replace)